# RobotFramework: Positional argument after varargs

Tags: robotframework

So i call this

```
Check All Fields Are Correct
...  @{field_dictionary}
...  test1
...  patients
```

and here is the keyword

```
Check All Fields Are Correct
    [Arguments]
    ...  @{field_dictionary}
    ...  ${db_name}
    ...  ${table_name}
```

But i get Positional argument after varargs error. I dont see anything obvious

Answer (score 1):

As described in RF guide, varargs (`@{field_dictionary}` in your case) have to be listed *after* positional arguments.
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#varargs-with-user-keywords

Answer (score 0):

`field_dictionary` should be declared as a scalar regardless of its type. Only use the `@` in an argument specification if you intend to use [varargs](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#varargs).

`[Arguments]
    ...  ${field_dictionary}`

And also use the scalar `$` when calling as well:

`Check All Fields Are Correct
...  ${field_dictionary}
...  test1
...  patients`